# Redirect users to login page if they are not login

Tags: java, grails, web, spring-security

When user is not logged in and he enter right url for login page then he goes on login page otherwise when user enter other url he will be redirected to error page instead of redirecting to login page. how to fix this?

Comment: What (if any) security plugin are you using and how do you have it configured?

Comment: I have spring security plugin in application. And every time it redirect me to the login page.

Comment: What about the second part of my question - how have you configured it?  The [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/requestMappings.html) suggests that by default everything that you have not specifically opened up will be forbidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `@Secure` annotation in your controller. This will redirect user to login page if not authorized. This Code :

```
@Secured(AuthenticatedVoter.IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY)
class CustomerController{
    ....
}
```

will redirect everyone how try to access customer view page unless they are logged in. they will be redirected to login page after trying to access this page. Although it is just a simple authentication and usually you need to do more than that, but it will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, the above answer is fine, but if you want to restrict more 
specfically, you can use this too

**First you should install Grails Spring Security plugin**

```
class UserController {

  // allow to access everyone
  def index() {
  }

  @Secured([UserRole.ROLE_USER,UserRole.ROLE_ADMIN,...])
  def account() {
  }
}
```

**Note**, if you are giving `@Secured` at the top of the class, will restrict the whole class from access

For your second question, you use `UrlMapping`, for example

```
"404"(controller:"yourController", action:"yourErrorPageAction")
```